# How to save event logs "Network Policy and Access Services" on NPS server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, nps

We have a Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise server with NPS role installed in it. (We dont use NAP). 
Is there any way, we can save all the event logs in------

> Event Viewer -> Custom Views -> Server Roles -> "Network Policy and Access Services".

I would prefer to do this using Windows PowerShell, and schedule this to save logs to a *.evt(x) file every 7 days.

The issue I see is I cant find any .evt file named as "Network Policy and Access Services", seems this is a custom made when we view it in the Event Viewer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should help -

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732912(v=ws.10).aspx

A brief of the link is as below, The link for *Configure NPS Event Logging* should be what you are looking for in particular.

## NPS logging

NPS logging is also called RADIUS accounting, and should be configured to your requirements whether NPS is used as a RADIUS server, proxy, NAP policy server, or any combination of the three configurations.

To configure NPS logging, you must configure the events logged and viewed with Event Viewer and determine other information you want to log. In addition, you must decide whether you want to log user authentication and accounting information to text log files stored on the local computer or to a SQL Server database on either the local computer or a remote computer.

The following Help sections provide the information you need to know to deploy RADIUS accounting.
RADIUS Accounting - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725566(v=ws.10).aspx

NPS Events and Event Viewer - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753898(v=ws.10).aspx

Configure NPS Event Logging - 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731085(v=ws.10).aspx